# javascript keydown and getElementById value issue

Tags: javascript

This is a part of my code:

```
button.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    var theVal = document.getElementById('theInput').value;
```

The problem is that the thing i'm copying into "theVal" is the thing i'm putting my key
down to. so here button is the same as theInput. so when a user enters:
**hey**

theVal actually holds:
**he**

so always the last key that was pressed isn't captured. How do i overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add event listener to `theInput` instead.
Also try to do the same thing in `OnkeyUp` event.

Answer (score 0):

Try onkeyup instead onkeydown.